# Connecting LVDS to oscilloscope using ferrite bead to isolate GND/SHIELD

Tags: oscilloscope, measurement, differential, isolation, lvds

I want to measure LVDS signals with a scope.

Will my solution work? (Shown at bottom.)

I know of other ways of doing this, but I am hoping this way is cleaner and easier.

Specs:

- Frequency:~100MHz
- Load:100Ω differential

Required:

- Measure DC-coupled signal levels (in reference to GND.) This cannot be inferred, it must be measured with decent accuracy.
  This solution won't cut it:
  [How to connect LVDS signals to oscilloscope?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/320590/how-to-connect-lvds-signals-to-oscilloscope)
- Measure differential amplitude (Q-*Q)
- Measure common-mode level (mean(Q+*Q))

Preferred:

- Avoid differential probes
- Use standard BNC or SMA terminating to 50Ω

I am using a ferrite bead to reference the SCOPE-GND to PCB-GND (for measuring DC levels). The bead blocks AC currents terminating to PCB-GND, insuring I(Q)=I(*Q)∙(-1).

[image: Problem Overview]

[image: My solution]

Comment: I don't understand what the stackup is showing. If that means a PCB, then first why is there a dedicated PCB design with poor grounding for this (test fixture I guess), whatever it is? Where would the transmission-lines diagram be applied? You say by the "AVOID" you cannot afford loading the signal (I guess) so terminating pairs into the scope seems N/A. Your "preferred" list subtly says "avoid diff probes" (plural) but "use standard [coax]" (singular), but you cannot read both DM and CM simultaneously over a single connection. And what's wrong with the "IDEAL" example, common ground?

Comment: A pair of good 10x RF passive probes might be the way to go. It's not difficult to make this type of probe yourself--a 450 Ω resistor (not wirewound) in series with a length of coax (I suggest RG-316, double-shielded if you like) terminating in the scope's 50 Ω termination impedance is all you need. You can also buy them premade, LeCroy sells one as the PP066 for instance.